# Folder heirarchy using just html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a VS Code-like folder hierarchy structure by just using HTML, CSS and vanilla javascript.

The image below shows what my goal is

[image: something like this]

But I'm finding it hard to:

- push new folders and files into deeply nested objects
- Vice-Versa getting them out of objects to be rendered into the DOM

The code snippet below is what I have. It can also be found and executed at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-oskar-kpxkzp?file=/src/index.html)

```js
const folderStruture = document.querySelector('#root')
const name = document.querySelector('#add-input')
const addBtn = document.querySelector('#add')
const app = document.querySelector('#root')
let fileCounter = 1
let folderCounter = 1
localStorage.setItem('folder', 'root')

const directory = [{
    id: 'root',
    name: 'root',
    isFolder: true,
    files: [{
        id: 'fd1',
        name: 'folder3',
        isFolder: true,
        files: []
      },
      {
        id: 'fl2',
        name: 'file2.js',
        isFolder: false
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'folder-2',
    name: 'folder',
    isFolder: true,
    files: []
  },
]

// update directory object

function createEntry(fName, folderID) {
  for (const dir of directory) {
    if (dir.id === folderID) {
      // file
      if (fName.match(/[.]/g) !== null) {
        dir.files.push({
          id: `fl-${fileCounter}`,
          name: fName,
          isFolder: false
        })
        fileCounter++
      }
      // folder
      else {
        dir.files.push({
          id: `fd-${folderCounter}`,
          name: fName,
          isFolder: true,
          files: [],
        })
        folderCounter++
      }
    } else {
      updateUI()
      addEvents()
      break
    }
  }
  console.log(folderID)
  console.log(directory)
}

// add new file or folder

addBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  createEntry(name.value, localStorage.getItem('folder'))
})

// render into dom

function updateUI() {
  app.innerHTML = ''
  directory.forEach((elem) => {
    if (elem.isFolder) {
      const ul = document.createElement('ul')
      ul.id = elem.id
      ul.textContent = elem.name
      ul.classList.add('folder')
      if (elem.files.length > 0) {
        elem.files.forEach((file) => {
          const li = document.createElement('li')
          li.id = file.id
          li.classList.add('file')
          li.textContent = file.name
          ul.appendChild(li)
        })
      }
      app.appendChild(ul)
    } else {}
  })
}

// active folder

function addEvents() {
  const folderList = document.querySelectorAll('.folder')
  folderList.forEach((folder) =>
    folder.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      folderList.forEach((f) => f.classList.remove('active'))
      e.target.classList.add('active')
      localStorage.setItem('folder', `${e.target.id}`)
    })
  )
  console.log(folderList)
}
```

```css
.btns {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  width: fit-content;
}

ul.folder::before,
li.file::before {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 1px;
  content: " ";
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-mask-size: cover;
}

ul.active {
  background-color: #31313146;
}

ul.folder::before {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("./assets/folder.png");
}

li.file::before {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("./assets/file.png");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Vite App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="btns">
      <div class="btn">
        <input type="text" id="add-input" />
        <button id="add">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul id="root" class="folder"></ul>
  <script type="module" src="./index.mjs"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using directly to your question. Also, do you have any **specific** question about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a hierarchical structure but a flat way of accessing it.

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Recursion - before calling `createEntry` create a function that calls itself on the children to find the folder.
2. Components - make the folder into a component that knows how to add sub folders (which are new copies of the same component) or files.

The latter is what most modern frameworks do, but you can also use [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components) in VanillaJS.

Recursion is simpler to do but harder to maintain:

```js
function createEntry(directory, fName, folderID) {
    for (const dir of directory) {
        if (dir.id === folderID) {
            // file
            if (fName.match(/[.]/g) !== null) {
                dir.files.push({ id: `fl-${fileCounter}`, name: fName, isFolder: false })
                fileCounter++
            }
            // folder
            else {
                dir.files.push({
                    id: `fd-${folderCounter}`,
                    name: fName,
                    isFolder: true,
                    files: [],
                })
                folderCounter++
            }
        } else if(dir.files?.length > 0) {
            // If there are child folders call this again to scan them
            createEntry(dir.files, fName, folderID);
        }
    }
}
```